# How to inspect elements on an iOS app where I do not have the source code

Tags: ios, ipad, automation, automated-tests

Hi I need to automate an application that I do not have the source code so it is completely blackbox.

Is there any way I can inspect elements of this application to continue my job?#

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[WebDriverAgent](https://github.com/facebook/WebDriverAgent) or [reveal](https://revealapp.com), maybe they can help u.

Comment: so can i only use the ipa file then?

Comment: can someone please answer this?